# Python CSV Parsing Dictionary and Finding Elements' Indices

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a CSV dictionary dictionary.txt that I want to use in my Python program. I already use the standard library csv to open the document. These are levels of difficulty the user will input to select a difficulty. If the user selects "EASY", I want to be able to ignore the headings, and be able to get the number of elements under the heading "EASY", up to just before the next difficulty. The number before the header is the level of difficulty. I have headings and data between those headings, similar to:

```
1, ##### EASY #####
key1, value1
key2, value2
2, ##### MEDIUM #####
key3, value3
key4, value4
3, ##### HARD #####
key5, value5
key6, value6
```

I want to return a dictionary-type of the useful elements in the dictionary (just key n, value n) for each section, and also an "ALL" option. My current code looks like this, but I don't know what to do from here:

```
with open("PLUG_dict.txt", "r") as db:
    mydict = dict(csv.reader(db))
for key in mydict.keys():
    if len(key) == 1:
        sections.append(mydict[key])
```

How do I:

- Find the index of a line of a specified difficulty (beginning and end)?
- Find the number of elements in between difficulties?
- Handle the last difficulty, "HARD", such that it won't become an error to run it to the end of the dictionary?
- If I wanted to include a classification, "ALL", that returned just all the useful elements in the dictionary, how to do that?

Comment: This is doable, but is there a reason you are not formatting your document like a normal CSV file -- i.e., `difficulty, key, value`?

Comment: why aren't we using python's data types instead, I dont get it at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, when you transform the content of your file into a dictionary, you will lose the order, as `dict` is unordered:

```
>>> dict(csv.reader(db))
{
  '1': ' ##### EASY #####',
  '3': ' ##### HARD #####',
  '2': ' ##### MEDIUM #####',
  'key3': ' value3',
  'key2': ' value2',
  'key1': ' value1',
  'key6': ' value6',
  'key5': ' value5',
  'key4': ' value4'
}
```

You can for example iterate through what `csv.reader(f)` returns to map exactly what you have in your file:

```
mydict = {}

with open("PLUG_dict.txt", "r") as db:
    for key, val in csv.reader(db):
        if len(key) == 1:
           # Difficulty line
           dif = key
           # Construct the entry for this difficulty, and save its name
           mydict[dif] = { 'name' : val }
        else:
           # key, val line
           # Simply add it in the dict of the current difficulty
           mydict[dif][key] = val
```

This will not work if the first line of your file is not a *"Difficulty line"*.
This will construct the following `mydict`

```
{
  '1': {
    'name': ' ##### EASY #####',
    'key1': ' value1',
    'key2': ' value2'
  },
  '3': {
    'name': ' ##### HARD #####',
    'key5': ' value5',
    'key6': ' value6'
  },
  '2': {
    'key3': ' value3',
    'name': ' ##### MEDIUM #####',
    'key4': ' value4'
  }
}
```

You can indeed change the way `'name'` is handled.

Then, with `dif = '1'`, you can:

- Find the values for a specified difficulty:

  ```
  mydict[dif]
  ```

  will return

  ```
  {
    'name': ' ##### EASY #####',
    'key1': ' value1',
    'key2': ' value2'
  }
  ```
- Find the number of element under a difficulty:

  ```
  len(mydict[dif]) - 1
  ```

  will return

  ```
  2
  ```

  Here, the `- 1` is necessary to remove `'name'` from the count. Depending on how you handle `'name'`, it could be discarded.
- Return all elements under every difficulty in a dictionary:

  ```
  {
    key: val
    for elements in mydict.values()
    for key, val in elements.items()
    if key != 'name'
  }
  ```

  will return

  ```
  {
    'key3': ' value3',
    'key2': ' value2',
    'key1': ' value1',
    'key6': ' value6',
    'key5': ' value5',
    'key4': ' value4'
  }
  ```

  Also here, depending on how you handle `'name'`, the condition `if key != 'name'` can be omitted.
- I am not sure to understand the question about `HARD` error?

I hope it helps!

Comment: This is perfect! The HARD error was just a concern if the reader needed some other "header" to mark the end of a difficulty section, which doesn't seem to be a problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along these lines:

```
import csv

with open('dictionary.txt', 'r') as f:
    data={}
    k=None 
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        print row
        if row[1] in ' ##### EASY ##### ##### MEDIUM ##### ##### HARD #####':
            k=row[1].strip()
            data[k]={}
        elif k:
            data[k][row[0]]=row[1]
```

Produces:

```
>>> data
{'##### HARD #####': {'key6': ' value6', 'key5': ' value5'}, '##### EASY #####': {'key2': ' value2', 'key1': ' value1'}, '##### MEDIUM #####': {'key3': ' value3', 'key4': ' value4'}}
```

Then access with `data[category][key_you_want_in_category]`

Answer (score 0):

Please Python's Data types are more suitable for this than the csv

use plug_dict.py instead and put this inside

```
levels = {'EASY': ["value 1", "value 2"],
      'MEDIUM': ["value 3", "value 4"],
      'HARD': ["value 5", "value 5"]
}
```

and do:

```
from plug_dict.py import levels

SECTIONS = []


#index of a particular line
Unnecessary, get the values instead
values_of_sect = levels['HARD']

# THE DIFFICULTIES
for key in levels:
    SECTIONS.append(key)


# no of elements in between difficulties
# do
elements = len(levels['HARD'])

# Handle the 'HARD' difficulty
unnecessary, python types handles it beautifully, you will get no errors
```